# How to add Material Design Tabs on a web app using unpkg as a storage for MDC CSS file and s file

Tags: javascript, tabs, material-design, mdc, mdc-components

I tried below html code for making a tab set:

```
<section id="dynamic-demo-toolbar">
  <nav id="dynamic-tab-bar" class="mdc-tab-bar" role="tablist">
    <a role="tab" aria-controls="panel-1"
       class="mdc-tab mdc-tab--active" href="#panel-1">Item One</a>
    <a role="tab" aria-controls="panel-2"
       class="mdc-tab" href="#panel-2">Item Two</a>
    <a role="tab" aria-controls="panel-3"
       class="mdc-tab" href="#panel-3">Item Three</a>
    <span class="mdc-tab-bar__indicator"></span>
  </nav>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="panels">
    <p class="panel active" id="panel-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">Item One</p>
    <p class="panel" id="panel-2" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">Item Two</p>
    <p class="panel" id="panel-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">Item Three</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dots">
    <a class="dot active" data-trigger="panel-1" href="#panel-1"></a>
    <a class="dot" data-trigger="panel-2" href="#panel-2"></a>
    <a class="dot" data-trigger="panel-3" href="#panel-3"></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

And JavaScript is:

```
<script>
var dynamicTabBar = window.dynamicTabBar = new mdc.tabs.MDCTabBar(document.querySelector('#dynamic-tab-bar'));
var dots = document.querySelector('.dots');
var panels = document.querySelector('.panels');

dynamicTabBar.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {?
  tab.preventDefaultOnClick = true;
});

function updateDot(index) {
  var activeDot = dots.querySelector('.dot.active');
  if (activeDot) {
    activeDot.classList.remove('active');
  }
  var newActiveDot = dots.querySelector('.dot:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')');
  if (newActiveDot) {
    newActiveDot.classList.add('active');
  }
}

function updatePanel(index) {
  var activePanel = panels.querySelector('.panel.active');
  if (activePanel) {
    activePanel.classList.remove('active');
  }
  var newActivePanel = panels.querySelector('.panel:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')');
  if (newActivePanel) {
    newActivePanel.classList.add('active');
  }
}

dynamicTabBar.listen('MDCTabBar:change', function ({detail: tabs}) {
  var nthChildIndex = tabs.activeTabIndex;

  updatePanel(nthChildIndex);
  updateDot(nthChildIndex);
});

dots.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  if (!evt.target.classList.contains('dot')) {
    return;
  }

  evt.preventDefault();

  var dotIndex = [].slice.call(dots.querySelectorAll('.dot')).indexOf(evt.target);

  if (dotIndex >= 0) {
    dynamicTabBar.activeTabIndex = dotIndex;
  }

  updatePanel(dotIndex);
  updateDot(dotIndex);
});
const MDCTab = mdc.tabs.MDCTab;
const MDCTabFoundation = mdc.tabs.MDCTabFoundation;

const MDCTabBar = mdc.tabs.MDCTabBar;
const MDCTabBarFoundation = mdc.tabs.MDCTabBarFoundation;
mdc.tabs.MDCTabBar.attachTo(document.querySelector('#my-mdc-tab-bar'));
</script>
```

please help me...
Where is the problem located and how do I solve it?
Actually Material.io doesn't provides sample full code for any components. That is why I got totally confused.
I'm making a chat app and tabs are required in there. So, I think you guys could help me. If possible, give any codepend or jsfiddle demo code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `?` sign in this line:

```
dynamicTabBar.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {?
```

And add some CSS for hiding non-active `panel` blocks by default:

```js
var dynamicTabBar = window.dynamicTabBar = new mdc.tabs.MDCTabBar(document.querySelector('#dynamic-tab-bar'));
var dots = document.querySelector('.dots');
var panels = document.querySelector('.panels');

dynamicTabBar.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
  tab.preventDefaultOnClick = true;
});

function updateDot(index) {
  var activeDot = dots.querySelector('.dot.active');
  if (activeDot) {
    activeDot.classList.remove('active');
  }
  var newActiveDot = dots.querySelector('.dot:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')');
  if (newActiveDot) {
    newActiveDot.classList.add('active');
  }
}

function updatePanel(index) {
  var activePanel = panels.querySelector('.panel.active');
  if (activePanel) {
    activePanel.classList.remove('active');
  }
  var newActivePanel = panels.querySelector('.panel:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')');
  if (newActivePanel) {
    newActivePanel.classList.add('active');
  }
}

dynamicTabBar.listen('MDCTabBar:change', function ({detail: tabs}) {
  var nthChildIndex = tabs.activeTabIndex;

  updatePanel(nthChildIndex);
  updateDot(nthChildIndex);
});

dots.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  if (!evt.target.classList.contains('dot')) {
    return;
  }

  evt.preventDefault();

  var dotIndex = [].slice.call(dots.querySelectorAll('.dot')).indexOf(evt.target);

  if (dotIndex >= 0) {
    dynamicTabBar.activeTabIndex = dotIndex;
  }

  updatePanel(dotIndex);
  updateDot(dotIndex);
});
const MDCTab = mdc.tabs.MDCTab;
const MDCTabFoundation = mdc.tabs.MDCTabFoundation;

const MDCTabBar = mdc.tabs.MDCTabBar;
const MDCTabBarFoundation = mdc.tabs.MDCTabBarFoundation;
mdc.tabs.MDCTabBar.attachTo(document.querySelector('#my-mdc-tab-bar'));
```

```css
.panel {
  display: none;
}

.panel.active {
  display: block
}

.dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dots {
  text-align: center;
}

.dot.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="dynamic-demo-toolbar">
  <nav id="dynamic-tab-bar" class="mdc-tab-bar" role="tablist">
    <a role="tab" aria-controls="panel-1"
       class="mdc-tab mdc-tab--active" href="#panel-1">Item One</a>
    <a role="tab" aria-controls="panel-2"
       class="mdc-tab" href="#panel-2">Item Two</a>
    <a role="tab" aria-controls="panel-3"
       class="mdc-tab" href="#panel-3">Item Three</a>
    <span class="mdc-tab-bar__indicator"></span>
  </nav>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="panels">
    <p class="panel active" id="panel-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">Item One</p>
    <p class="panel" id="panel-2" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">Item Two</p>
    <p class="panel" id="panel-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">Item Three</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dots">
    <a class="dot active" data-trigger="panel-1" href="#panel-1"></a>
    <a class="dot" data-trigger="panel-2" href="#panel-2"></a>
    <a class="dot" data-trigger="panel-3" href="#panel-3"></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Console says: `MESSAGE: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { LINE: 81 IN: http://localhost:3000/test.html LEVEL: ERROR ` where 81th line is given below: `dynamicTabBar.listen('MDCTabBar:change', function({detail: tabs}){            var nthChildIndex = tabs.activeTabIndex; ............. `

Comment: @NodeDev there is code snippet in my answer you can run it and see that works. But here is jsfiddle if you want http://jsfiddle.net/maxsinev/402hmest/